# hadoop java.io.IOException: while running namenode -format

Tags: hadoop, directory, ioexception, java-io

I ran namenode -format.This is my output. I tried changing the file permissions chmod 777 hadoop.

I believe this line is the error
 ERROR namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /your/path/to/hadoop/tmp/dir/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name/current

```
adoop@alexander-desktop:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ ./hadoop namenode -format
12/07/03 17:03:56 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = alexander-desktop/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.2
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20 -r 911707; compiled by 'chrisdo' on Fri Feb 19 08:07:34 UTC 2010
************************************************************/
12/07/03 17:03:56 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hadoop,hadoop
12/07/03 17:03:56 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
12/07/03 17:03:56 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
12/07/03 17:03:56 ERROR namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /your/path/to/hadoop/tmp/dir/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name/current
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:1086)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:1110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:856)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:948)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:965)

12/07/03 17:03:56 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at alexander-desktop/127.0.1.1


hadoop@alexander-desktop:/usr/local$ sudo hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0777, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Comment: you may probably need to stop your all daemons first before performing format on namenode..!

Comment: There is an error in your `hdfs-site.xml`; there is no such path called `/your/path/to/hadoop/tmp/dir/..`. It is possible that you followed a template for your `hdfs-site.xml` but forgot to edit the parameters. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49891321/4565943) for a similar problem I faced and its solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try with sudo (I realize you changed permissions) but I would still try sudo and check if that resolves the problem.

Comment: i fixed the error above by changing the permission level for sudoers. The original error has not been resolved. ok I now have a problem with $JAVA_HOME can I use export $JAVA_HOME and the path to fix the error

Comment: @alex: Did you set $JAVA_HOME in conf/hadoop-env.sh? Check if your environment has this JAVA_HOME set. Note that sudo user environment and you environment are different. Use commands printev and sudo printenv.

Comment: thanks that fixed the problem I also experimented with settings various environmental variables so i found it worthwhile learning experience. What confused me is the tutorial said you could set either hadoop-env.sh or bash.bashrc file.

Comment: What is the best method is it to enviroment variables or is it better to set profile.d file.

Comment: @alex What permission did you change for sudoers file? Iam facing the same problem

Comment: @FourOfAKind I have tried using sudo but still it is going back to /dfs/nn whereas i have given a different location in the core-site.xml .Kindly help

Answer (score 13):

Following steps resolved my problem -

1- sudo su

Enter your password.

2-/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs namenode -format.

This has been done for hadoop2.5 in which "hadoop namenode -format" has beendeprecated hence using "hdfs namenode -format"

Comment: Worked for me, thank you! The accepted answer didn't work in my case

Comment: same for me .. The accepted answer didn't work in my case.. this worked~

Answer (score 2):

Check hdfs-site.xml configuration, it may has a wrong path for properties
dfs.namenode.name.dir and dfs.datanode.data.dir
In my case it was the cause of the problem (directory was situated in other then current user's home folder).

Comment: I think everyone is going nuclear with sudo - the error message says: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /your/path/to/hadoop/tmp/dir/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name/current  -- wouldn't this mean that what ever place holder value for the datadir directory doesn't exist?  Check your default values in core-site.xml of hdfs-site.xml first?

Answer (score 2):

This is a permissions issue.
Either you can use
1. sudo
2. login as root

But the best solution is

sudo chown $HADOOP_HOME

hadoop namenode -format

Where HADOOP_HOME is your hadoop installation directory

Comment: sudo chown $HADOOP_HOME to what permission?

Answer (score 0):

sudo is broken in this situation, but `pkexec` (the command-line frontend to PolicyKit) still works, so you can fix it with a single command. No rebooting is necessary.

```
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

This assumes `PolicyKit` is installed. If this is a desktop system (rather than a server with no GUI), it is.