# Cannot create directory /home/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode/current

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I get the error

```
Cannot create directory /home/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode/current
```

While trying to install hadoop on my local Mac.

What could be the reason for this? Just for reference, I'm putting my xml files down below:

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

   <property> 
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>

   <property>
      <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode </value>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>dfs.data.dir</name> 
      <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/datanode </value> 
   </property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp</value>
    <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I think my problem lies in my hdfs-site.xml file, but I'm not sure how to pinpoint/change it.

I'm using [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm) tutorial, and "hadoop" in the file path is replaced by my username.

Comment: check directory permissions

Answer (score 8):

**Possible error:** misconfiguration of the `hdfs-site.xml` file

This happened to me when I was following a setup tutorial. The contents of the `hdfs-site.xml` for me was

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
            <value>/home/hadoop/data/nameNode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
            <value>/home/hadoop/data/dataNode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Only then I realized that the text `hadoop` in the above file corresponds to the user name, where in my case, it had to replaced with `hduser`. When both occurrences of `hadoop` was replaced with `hduser`, the `hdfs namenode -format` command worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem too and it was a permission problem. I just did:

> sudo chmod 777 /home/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode/

and works!

Comment: as a note, this is setting wide open permissions to the directory though. Not a good practice in a production environment, but it does solve the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: Surely, it is not a good practice in a production environment.

Comment: You could do this instead sudo chown username:username -R /path/to/hadoopNodes/namenode/

Answer (score 0):

In the step where you need to verify the hadoop installation, instead of 'hdfs namenode -format' use '/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs namenode -format'

Found this answer from:
[hadoop java.io.IOException: while running namenode -format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315177/hadoop-java-io-ioexception-while-running-namenode-format)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any other distro than native hadoop, then add the current user to hadoop group and retry formatting the namenode.

```
sudo usermod -a -G hadoop <current-username>
```

In case of using thirdparty hadoop distros such Cloudera, Hortonworks or MapR, switch to root user and again switch to hdfs user then try formatting the namenode will succeed.

```
$ sudo -i 
$ su - hdfs
$ hdfs namenode -format
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Hadoop command with sudo